# autocomplete="on" is working only reload or refresh the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angular-local-storage

I want to preserve some search history in the input text box, then I put autocomplete="on" attribute on my input field, but it's only work when the page is either reloaded or refreshed.

Here is what I refer localStorage method in the app.js, I can save the input history console like ["123123","123123","abc123","dkiwksiwdADS","33333","555555","QWQWQWQW"], but how can i put these saved history when double click in the textbox(may be a div in the index.html)??

**My code:**
 app.js:

```
......                               
        search.getHistory = function() {
                                        console.log($window.localStorage.myObj);
                                        }

        search.runreportsearch = function () {
            var history;
                                        if ($window.localStorage.myObj){
                                            history = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.myObj);
                                            if (angular.isArray(history)){
                                                history.push(search.searchboxinput);
                                            } else {
                                                history = [];
                                                history.push(search.searchboxinput);
                                            }
                                            $window.localStorage.myObj=JSON.stringify(history);
                                            console.log($window.localStorage.myObj);
                                        } else {
                                            history = [];
                                            history.push(search.searchboxinput);
                                            $window.localStorage.myObj=JSON.stringify(history);
                                            console.log($window.localStorage.myObj);
```

index.html

```
        <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h4><input type="text" class="form-control text-center" ng-model="search.searchboxinput" ng-dblclick="search.getHistory()" placeholder="Enter term to search"/></h4>
            </div>
```

Comment: `autocomplete=on` is only record history when you submitted form ! So as you say ,it will works only after refresh(form submitted)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. how can I make the input save take effect immediately by not reloading the page?

Comment: You can use local storage

Comment: Can you specify how can i use local storage in this case? thank you